# I can see cassandra is CPU bound for write heavy work loads but is it network bound as well?

Tags: networking, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-2.1

**SETUP: 1**

3-node cassandra cluster. Each node is on a different machine with **4 cores** 32 GB RAM, 800GB SSD (DISK), 1Gbit/s = 125 MBytes/sec Network bandwith

2 cassandra-stress client machines with same exact configuration as above.

**Experiment1:** Ran one client on one machine creating anywhere from 1 to 1000 threads and with Conistency Level of Quorum and the max network throughput on a cassandra node was around 8MBytes/sec with a CPU Usage of 85-90 percent on both cassandra node and the client

**Experiment2:** Ran two clients on two different machines creating anywhere from one to 1000 threads with Conistency Level of Quorum and the max network throughput on a cassandra node was around 12MBytes/sec with a CPU Usage of 90 percent on both cassandra node and both the client

Did not see double the throughput even though my clients were running on two different machines but I can understand the cassandra node is CPU bound and thats probably why. so that lead me to setup2

**SETUP 2**

3-node cassandra cluster. Each node is on a different machine with **8 cores** 32 GB RAM, 800GB SSD (DISK), 1Gbit/s = 125 MBytes/sec Network bandwith

2 cassandra-stress client machines with 4 cores 32 GB RAM, 800GB SSD (DISK), 1Gbit/s = 125 MBytes/sec Network bandwith

**Experiment3:** Ran one client on one machine creating anywhere from 1 to 1000 threads and with Conistency Level of Quorum and the max network throughput on a cassandra node was around 18MBytes/sec with a CPU Usage of 65-70 percent on a cassandra node and >90% on the client node.

**Experiment4:** Ran two clients on two different machines creating anywhere from 1 to 1000 threads and with Conistency Level of Quorum and the max network throughput on a cassandra node was around 22MBytes/sec with a CPU Usage of <=75 percent on a cassandra node and >90% on both client nodes.

so the question here is with one client node I was able to push 18MB/sec (Network throughput) and with two client nodes running two different machine I was only able to push at a peak of 22MB/sec(Network throughput) ?? And I wonder why this is the case even though this time the cpu usage on cassandra node is around 65-70 percent on a 8 core machine.

**Note:** I stopped cassandra and ran a tool called iperf3 on two different ec2 machines and I was able to see the network bandwith of 118 MBytes/second. I am converting everything into Bytes rather than bits to avoid any sort of confusion.

Comment: I clearly stated that I indeed measured it using iperf3.

Comment: ofcourse I used iperf3 to measure the maximum network bandwith of an instance and the other network throughput numbers I was reporting is something I got from "sudo iftop -B"

Comment: I missed that part of your problem description.

Comment: Idea: during the tests, run a *dstat* and look at the network bandwidth column to check whether you can correlate network traffic wth CPU usage. Same for disk I/O, although I think you shouldn't have issue there since you're using SSD but who knows